# Unable to Import statements while adding external library manually in Android

Tags: java, android, android-library

I don't want to use an external library by using

```
   compile 'com.github.atomfrede:jadenticon:1.1.0'
```

from gradle.

Hence I am manually adding all the java files of the library in my android stuidio project.(I know this is dumb and time consuming)

However,I am unable to use foreign import statements(unable to resolve error) like

```
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

I know these are not default android or java classes and perhaps hence the error.
But then how is the original library be able to use such import statements.

How can i use these import statements in my project.

Comment: Gradle is a building tool that would download the libraries dependencies automatically, but since you don't want to use gradle you're going the have to install the dependencies manually yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because as far as I know when you add a library as a dependency and you sync gradle it also downloads the library dependencies(dependencies the library project depend upon), so that library is able to access those import statements.

In your case , what you are trying (which is a bit dumb as you said ;) ) , you can search those classes in Google and will find the jar file containing those files or the independent files itself.

Comment: The dependencies are also mentioned [here](https://github.com/atomfrede/jadenticon/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks for the info

Comment: SatyenUdeshi & @JornVernee Thanks a ton